# Read each line of txt file to new array element

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, fgets

I am trying to read every line of a text file into an array and have each line in a new element.
My code so far.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("members.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file);
$members = explode('\n', $line_of_text);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: Is anything stored in the array with your code as it is? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Warning: FALSE from fopen will issue warning and result in infinite loop here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php

Comment: Despite the thread's date an `'\n\'` won't be exploded while it must be a `"\n"` to have it parsed as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 428):

If you don't need any special processing, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) should do what you're looking for

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: `file()` seems to be considerably slower than `file_get_contents` + `explode` to array

Comment: @Ron I agree. Then again, you shouldn't read a file this way at every request. That's just silly, even if the solution is optimal. The content of the file should either be stored on memory cache, or even in a database. Even PHP stores the content of parsed files. I mean, we're far from PHP 4.3

Answer (score 46):

The fastest way that I've found is:

```
// Open the file
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
```

where $filename is going to be the path & name of your file, eg. ../filename.txt.

Depending how you've set up your text file, you'll have might have to play around with the \n bit.

Comment: I would use "PHP_EOL" instead of "\n", this looks so, $array = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

Comment: Thanks Drew, after trying many functions, yours is the only one that worked. My search term being <br> instead of your \n. My file was being read as only a single big value array, whole text was just one array item $myarr[0], so shuffling did not work on a single item. Hope it helps someone. Thanks again.

Answer (score 40):

Just use this:

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 30):

```
$yourArray = file("pathToFile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` avoid to add newline at the end of each array element 
You can also use `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` to Skip empty lines

reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Answer (score 23):

```
<?php
$file = fopen("members.txt", "r");
$members = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $members[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

var_dump($members);
?>
```

Comment: Okay I have it working perfectly thanks. However I need to set a vaiable = to an array element. $var = $ary[1]; does not work. ary[1]= "test". If that helps.

Comment: Run a counter yourself and set the index in the array

Comment: [why `while(!feof($file))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Answer (score 13):

It's just easy as that:

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('foo.txt'));
```

`file_get_contents()` - gets the whole file as string.

`explode("\n")` - will split the string with the delimiter `"\n"` - what is ASCII-LF escape for a newline.

But pay attention - check that the file has **UNIX**-Line endings.

If `"\n"` will not work properly you have another coding of newline and you can try `"\r\n"`, `"\r"` or `"\025"`

Answer (score 7):

```
$lines = array();
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false)
    array_push($lines, $line);
```

Obviously, you'll need to create a file handle first and store it in `$file`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = __DIR__."/file1.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$array1 = array();

while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) )
{
    $nl = mb_strtolower($line,'UTF-8');
    $array1[] = $nl;
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but there were some problems with the code you posted. First of all, there was no closing bracket for the while loop. Secondly, $line_of_text would be overwritten with every loop iteration, which is fixed by changing the = to a .= in the loop. Third, you're exploding the literal characters '\n' and not an actual newline; in PHP, single quotes will denote literal characters, but double quotes will actually interpret escaped characters and variables.

```
    <?php
        $file = fopen("members.txt", "r");
        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line_of_text .= fgets($file);
        }
        $members = explode("\n", $line_of_text);
        fclose($file);
        print_r($members);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $file = file("links.txt");
print_r($file);
```

This will be accept the txt file as array. So write anything to the links.txt file (use one line for one element) after, run this page :) your array will be $file

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered here quite well, but if you **REALLY** need even better performance than anything listed here, you can use this approach that uses `strtok`.

```
$Names_Keys = [];
$Name = strtok(file_get_contents($file), "\n");
while ($Name !== false) {
    $Names_Keys[$Name] = 0;
    $Name = strtok("\n");
}
```

Note, this assumes your file is saved with `\n` as the newline character (you can update that as need be), and it also stores the words/names/lines as the array keys instead of the values, so that you can use it as a lookup table, allowing the use of `isset` (much, much faster), instead of `in_array`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP_EOL.

```
$dataLines = explode(PHP_EOL, $documentVariable);
```