# I am trying to read every line from a txt file and have to perform action for every new line

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have one txt file which contain many lines.
I have to use those lines one by one for executing a code. that data of single line i have to save in a variable. i have to perform same action for every line.

Comment: Use `file` function to have each line as array item, then loop through array

Comment: actually i have access_token i have to use them for performing some action. each access_token is in new line. so i have to use one by one all access token

Comment: i tried file function. but i dont have much knowledge to array. so i am unable to set arry or loop for performing action.

Comment: $m=file_get_contents('http://example.com/a.txt');

$file=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$m);

Comment: for each access token i have to perform task. i have many accesstoken in file a.txt . as line change access token change.

Answer (score 1):

The line end character ("\n") might need to be changed depending on the platform where the text file is generated, but this should set you on the right track:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');

$lines = explode("\n", $file);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    ...
}
```

For lots of other ways [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element).