# How to set each line of a text file as a variable?

Tags: php

I got a simple php script that is storing the content of POST  in to a text file. data.txt looks like this:

```
Something - Line1
Something - Line2
Something - Line3
Something - Line4
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set each line as a variable e.g.

```
$line1 = "Something - Line1";
$line2 = "Something - Line2";
$line3 = "Something - Line3";
$line4 = "Something - Line4;"
```

so I can use it for further processing. Please note that the numbers of line can change. Any ideas? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best to use an array.  Check out [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.txt');
```

Then you access the lines starting from `0`:

```
echo $lines[0];
echo $lines[1];
//etc...
```

Or loop through them:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: *"Please note that the numbers of line can change."* - The loop will be better, instead of OP hardcoding the arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  Agreed, just making sure they are aware of arrays and how to use them.  Normally this type of question means no.

Comment: Indeed, it's always good for OP's to know how arrays work. +1 btw ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

This link provides your answer: [Read each line of txt file to new array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element)

The link makes use of the while loop and searches for the end of the file

The link provided uses the following code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("members.txt", "r");
$members = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $members[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

var_dump($members);
?>
```

Comment: Links to answers or other external pages are discouraged. Links/pages could be deleted.