# PHP transforming file in Json adds one more line

Tags: php, json

i'm pretty new with PHP. So i find this code on the internet and modify it to what i need,but it seems that it gives me one more value in array ,sometimes.

when csv looks like this
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4

it's fine but when i got
a:1,2,3,4
b:1,2,3,4
c:1,2,3,4
d:1,2,3,4

it adds one more empty line.
why is that and can i prevent that?

```
<?php
$csv_mimetypes = array(
    'text/csv',
    'text/plain',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.msexcel',
    'text/anytext',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/txt',);

 if ($_FILES["csv"]["error"] > 0)
{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('no file');</script>";
}
elseif(in_array ($_FILES["csv"]["type"] ,$csv_mimetypes))
{
//get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];    
    $csv= file_get_contents($file);
     $array = explode("\r\n", $csv);
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $array[$i] = explode(';', $array[$i]);
}

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK!');</script>";
}
else
 {
 echo "File must be a .csv";
  }
?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Bar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myJsarray = <?= json_encode($array); ?> ;
```

Comment: The example you provide do not contain any semicolon (`;`) character, however, you are doing `explode(';', $array[$i])`... Plus, what is the actual output versus the expected output?

Comment: the csv files have semicolons,so I guess that's not a problem. 
i'm outputting the values form the array into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `file_get_content` with `file` to read [each line into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element/6159705#6159705).

#### Example:

```
// $array = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$array = array("id;podaci1;podaci2", "grad1;25;21", "grad2;23;28", "grad3;45;32");

array_walk($array, function (& $line) {
   $line = explode(';', $line);
});

$json = json_encode($array);

print_r($json);
```

#### Output

```
[["id","podaci1","podaci2"],["grad1","25","21"],["grad2","23","28"],["grad3","45","32"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your csv files all terminate the same way?
I mean: I suppose that when you get one additional empty line at the bottom of your array, the corresponding csv file terminates with an additional field separator (`;`) or line separator (`\r\n`)...

Comment: the csv files are made in excel,so i guess they are.

Comment: excel...made a table..save as csv..?

Comment: O.k. Please open a file which gives a good array and one which gives a wrong one (using your preferred text editor). Then check if they terminate the same way: I suspect one will have an additional `;` or `\r\n`... It's not due to a bug in MS Excel, but to the way you did create them...

Comment: i did..they look like this
working one
aaa;46  

bbb;23  

ccc;51  

ddd;23  

the one that dosn't work
id;podaci1;podaci2  
grad1;25;21  
grad2;23;28  
grad3;45;32

Comment: Did you doublecheck for an extra empty line at the end of file that doesn't work?

Comment: i have more files like the exemple i give you and they all are not working

Comment: The fact your issue is solved by `file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`, as in the accepted answer - proves some of your files (the "NOT WORKING" ones) had some trailing new lined you were not aware of.