# Get random lines from text file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I want to call random words from the `random.txt` as the user refreshes the page but I get `$word_array[0]` only and not any other $word_array[1..3].

random.txt

```
hello
how
are
you
```

PHP code:

```
myfile = fopen("random.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$word_array = array(fgets($myfile));

$word = rand(0,4);
$lines[] = fgets($myfile);
echo $word_array[$word];

fclose ($myfile);
```

What is the error?

update: If loops can be avoided, and correct this code only.

Comment: didn't this give you an offset error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that you put just the first line of your file into an array here:

```
$word_array = array(fgets($myfile));
```

Means what you have here is:

```
Array (
    [0] => First line
)
```

So if you have [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on you would get a notice:

> Notice:  Undefined offset

75% of the time.

But to do what you want you can just use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get your file into an array combined with [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), e.g.

```
$lines = file("random.txt");
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

Comment: `fgets` gets only one line, not the entire file. The `file()` solution is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

fgets are read only one line by line.
so you need something like:

```
$lines[] = fgets($myfile);
$lines[] = fgets($myfile);
$lines[] = fgets($myfile);
$lines[] = fgets($myfile);
echo $lines[$word];
```

4 times for 4 lines

Answer (score 0):

Short: fgets just read one line
You need to create a while-statement to read all lines.

So:

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('random.txt'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

[Read each line of txt file to new array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element)

Comment: Excuse me: this does not read `random` line as OP stated, yes? Even if your txt file's name is `random`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesing question=) You can try my solution:

```
$myfile = fopen("random.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$words = fgets($myfile);//gets only first line of a file
$num = str_word_count($words) - 1 ;//count number of words, but array index
//starts from 0, so we need -1
$word_array = explode(' ', $words);//gets all words as array

$word = rand(0,$num);//getting random word number
echo $word_array[$word];

fclose ($myfile);
```

if you need all lines - you have to iterate over all lines with, for example, while loop

```
while($row = fgets($myfile)){
    //same code
}
```