# PHP - while loop (!feof()) isn't outputting/showing everything

Tags: php, while-loop, output, fopen

I am trying to read (and echo) **everything** of a .txt-File.

This is my code:

```
$handle = @fopen("item_sets.txt", "r");

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    $trimmed = trim($buffer);
    echo $trimmed;
}
```

This is my "item_sets.txt": http://pastebin.com/sxapZGuW

But it doesn't echo everything (and changing how much it shows depending on if and how many characters i echo after it). `var_dump()` shows me that the last string is never finished printing out. That looks like this:

`" string(45) ""[cu_well_tra`. But if I put an

`echo "whateverthisisjustarandomstringwithseveralcharacters";`,

my last output lines look like this:

`" string(45) ""[cu_well_traveled_ak47]weapon_ak47" "1"
" string(5) "}
"`

Basically my code isn't printing/echoing all of what it should or at least not showing it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why not using `print file_get_contents()` here?

Comment: @ob_start still isn't printing everything

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code - it reads all the lines and outputs them. _Except_ `trim` 'eats' all the `end of line` markers so when you echo you need to use `PHP_EOL`. i,e. `echo $trimmed, PHP_EOL;`. Otherwise you get one long line of output.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because your test for EOF is before you output your last read

Try this with the test for EOF as part of the reading process

```
<?php
$line_count = 0;

$handle = fopen("item_sets.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {

    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $trimmed = trim($buffer);
        echo $trimmed;
        $line_count++;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Unexpected error opening file';
}
fclose($handle);

echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'Lines read from file = ' . $line_count;
?>
```

Also I removed the `@` infront of the `fopen` its bad practice to ignore errors, and much better practice to look for them and deal with them.

I copied your data into a file called tst.txt and ran this exact code

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('tst.txt', 'r');

if ($handle) {

    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $trimmed = trim($buffer);
        echo $trimmed;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Unexpected error opening file';
}
fclose($handle);
```

And it generated this output ( just a small portion shown here )

```
"item_sets"{"set_community_3"{"name"            "#CSGO_set_community_3""set_description"                "#CSGO_set_community_3_desc""is_collection"
```

And the last output is

```
[aa_fade_revolver]weapon_revolver"          "1"
```

Which is the last entry in the data file

Comment: This is also not printing everything :/ Could this just be an output problem ?

Comment: Add the debug line, to see if it is actually going round that loop at all

Comment: Well ... now it's not showing anything anymore, it's literally not even showing my html document I had around besides the navigation bar

Comment: And have you looked in your `php error log` for any hints. Also remember I can only see what you have shown me, I see no html therefore I treated this as a stand alone piece of code

Comment: Last log of the error log was when I tried to print it out with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: What happens when you remove the debug line

Comment: It shows me that `$trimmed` is `1`, and that maaany times ... I am wondering, I did this before with another file and it was working fine there.

Comment: That file looks like it is ALMOST a JSON string, Is that what it is supposed to be?

Comment: But ... what difference would it make if i'm just reading it line by line and saving it as a string ? It shouldn't be affected actually (at least I think so).

Comment: Hmmm I just tried it and yes it gives lots of `11111111` let me play for a minute

Comment: Haaaaaa. See amendment. All for the want of a set of brackets. Its late here, sorry missed that completely

Comment: So you have a solution? :)

Comment: Yes. Look at the extra brackets in `while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {` line

Comment: And this is printing out everything in your code ? Could you please post the full code because it's still not working for me ...

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, I even put the code and the text of the textfile in another file and tried it but it's still not printing out everything...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98806/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-njoye).