# fgets() response null when Dynamically subdomain creation

Tags: php, subdomain

I want to create dynamically subdomain. When i echoing `fputs()`, it displays some digits which means its working but when we are retrieving data using `fgets()`, getting null. Here is my code.

```
// your cPanel username
$cpanel_user = 'username';

// your cPanel password
$cpanel_pass = 'password';

// your cPanel skin
$cpanel_skin = 'x';

// your cPanel domain
$cpanel_host = 'domain.com';

// subdomain name
$subdomain = 'mysubdomain';

// create the subdomain

$sock = fsockopen($cpanel_host,80, $errno, $errstr, 60);
if(!$sock) {
echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
  print('Socket error');
  exit();
}
echo $sock."<br>";
$pass = base64_encode("$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass");
echo "$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass<br>";
$in = "GET /frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$cpanel_host&domain=$subdomain\r\n";
$in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$in .= "Host:$cpanel_host\r\n";
$in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";
$in .= "\r\n";
echo $in."<br>";
$result="";
fputs($sock, $in);
while (!feof($sock)) {
  $result .= fgets ($sock);
}
fclose($sock);

echo "Result:- ".$result;
```

i am not getting where i am wrong.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using `file_get_contents` or `cURL`?

Comment: `HTTP/1.0`  should be on the same line as `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP is not formatted correctly. The `GET` line is supposed to be:

```
GET <pathname> <HTTPversion>
```

but you're sending

```
GET <pathname>
<HTTPversion>
```

Change these lines:

```
$in = "GET /frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$cpanel_host&domain=$subdomain\r\n";
$in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
```

to

```
$in = "GET /frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$cpanel_host&domain=$subdomain HTTP/1.0\r\n";
```

You also shouldn't use

```
while (!feof($sock))
```

See [PHP - while loop (!feof()) isn't outputting/showing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything). Instead, use:

```
while ($line = fgets($sock)) {
    $result .= $line;
}
```

But you could simplify all of this by using `file_get_contents`

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass@$cpanel_host/frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=$cpanel_host&domain=$subdomain");
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar,after deploye the code as you suggested I am getting HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 12:19:14 GMT Server: Apache Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Content-Type: text/html Erreur 404

Comment: That means the path `/frontend/$cpanel_skin/subdomain/doadddomain.html` is wrong.

Comment: wildcard dns and * mapping will be use in cpanel?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't know anything about cpanel, it's not a programming question. If you have questions about using cpanel, serverfault.com would be a better place to ask.

Comment: ok, i mean is it the complete process to make subdomain or anything would be change on server.

Comment: I have no idea. I said I don't know anything about cpanel, so I don't know what the URL does. I assume you know what the URL does, and you just need to know how to do the PHP part.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for quick answer. I am not getting the subdomain name so i am confuse. I will check it. appreciated, thanks