# PHP pipe program

Tags: php, pipe, cpanel

I am trying to setup a PIPE connection from an email on a subdomain on my server. I cannot for the life of me find the error, for security reasons I have removed several peices of information, but I have placed everything I believe is reuqired.

```
Return-path: <>
Envelope-to: ** REDACTED **
Delivery-date: Sun, 01 Jan 2017 08:39:00 -0600
Received: from mailnull by **REDACTED** with local (Exim 4.87)
id 1cNhHo-00052H-2p for **REDACTED**; Sun, 01 Jan 2017 08:39:00 -0600
X-Failed-Recipients: **EMAIL ADDRESS UTILIZED**
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@myf.myfallen.net>
To: **REDACTED**
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status; boundary=1483281540-eximdsn-172165259
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
Message-Id: <E1cNhHo-00052H-2p@myf.myfallen.net>
Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2017 08:39:00 -0600
X-EsetId: 37303A29489795666C7762
```

cPanel pipe to email:

> **EMAIL**     |/home/**USER**/public_html/staff/core/emailTicket.php

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/php  -q
<?php
require('error.php');
require('connection.php');
require('email/bannedemail.php');    
require('email/newEmailTicket.php');  
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email_content = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email_content .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fh);

$lines = explode("\n", $email_content);

$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$is_header = true;

//loop through each line
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($is_header) {
        // hear information. instead of main message body, all other information are here.
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

        // Split out the subject portion
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        //Split out the sender information portion
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // content/main message body information
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $is_header = false;
    }
}
```

** My code goes below **

PHP Info:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini

I have searched multiple places for an answer and still cannot find anything.

Email Error:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> pipe to |/home/**USERNAME**/public_html/staff/core/emailTicket.php
> generated by **EMAIL**
> local delivery failed

Comment: Instead of the loop, you can just use `$email_content = file_get_contents("php://stdin");`

Comment: Make sure the script has execute permission.

Comment: [why `while(!feof($fh))` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Typo here: `fclose($fh);` should be `fclose($fd);`

Comment: Hi Barmar, Permissions are set as 755

Comment: Hi All, the actual issue was I was doing it wrong, I had to put in |php -q /directory/to/script/ in the email filters NOT in the FORWARDERS

Comment: @NoMansLand hi, could you help me with what's |php -q /directory/to/script/ I am running into same "mail delivery failed" issue. I am on linux cpanel.