# Reading a file contents into a table via PHP

Tags: php, html, file, html-table

```
<?php
function lineNumber($file){
    $linecount = 0;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $line = fgets($handle);
        $linecount++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo $linecount;
}

?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>subnet</th>
    <th>mask</th>
    <th>via</th>
    <th>option</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    $l1=lineNumber("other/network/route/via.txt");
for ($i=0; $i <$l1 ; $i++) { 
    $file="other/network/route/via.txt";

    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $line = fgets($handle);
        echo" 
            <tr>
                        <td>" '$line';"</td>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Carter</td>
                        <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                        <td></td>
           </tr>
             ";
    }
}

fclose($handle);

?>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to read a some text file and put each line of file contents to a row of table. Each column has a file. And then I have column for deleting each row and also deleting the contents of that row in file. So how can I do it?

Comment: [why `while (!feof($handle)` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Why do you have both a `for()` loop and `while()` loop? This will display the same file over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen("other/network/route/via.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```