# Affects variables in php with popen

Tags: php

I have this php code :

```html
<?php 
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("test.o", 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    $a = fread($proc, 1);;
 echo $a;
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and test.o which comes from test.c :

test.c :

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
 int a=0;
  int b=1;
 printf("%d\n",a);
 printf("%d\n",b);
}
```

When I run the php code it give me 0 and 1, but how do you affect this two numbers in each new variables ?

I mean, I would like to put each line in a variable and after I made echo of one variable for example.

The fact is that after this exemple I will use it for reading data from another C file which the output will be not only 2 lines but an undefined lines.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless `popen` is needed just `exec("test.o", $output);` and array will contain each line of output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()` to read a line. Do it in a loop that adds to an array.

```
$proc = popen("test.o", 'r');
$lines = array();
while ($line = fgets($proc)) {
    $lines[] = trim($line);
}
pclose($proc);
var_dump($lines);
```

`trim()` will remove the newlines after each line.

See also [PHP - while loop (!feof()) isn't outputting/showing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: The fact is that after this exemple I will use it for reading data from another C file which the output will be not only 2 lines but an undefined lines.

Comment: In that case call `fgets()` in a loop and push them onto an array.