# Foreach loop importing lines from csv gets 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' at only 1 specific row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a loop to import each line from a CSV into a database. It works fine, except there is one row in the CSV that gets the error:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I have looked at the row and cannot seem to notice any difference between it and the other rows, and yet if I remove this row everything works fine and it imports the whole file.

Here is the loop:

```
$filters = ["batches", "batches-2"];

// Import the SKU filters file First

foreach($filters as $filter) {
    if(!empty($location = $_FILES[$filter]['tmp_name'])) { // For each file, check if it's empty
        $file = fopen($location, "r");
        $filearray = fgetcsv($file);
        while(!feof($file)) { // For each file uploaded:
            $filearray = fgetcsv($file);
            $batch = $filearray['1'];
            if(!empty($batch)) {

                $skusearchquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['0']);
                $fees =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['2']);
                $costofgoods =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['3']);
                $number =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['4']);
                $lister =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['5']);
                $listerfee =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['6']);
                $tier1a =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['7']);
                $tier1asplit =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['8']);
                $tier1b =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['9']);
                $tier1bsplit =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['10']);
                $tier1c =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['11']);
                $tier1csplit =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['12']);
                $tier1d =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['13']);
                $tier1dsplit =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['14']);
                $tier1e =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['15']);
                $tier1esplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['16']);
                $tier2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['17']);
                $tier2split = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['18']);
                $tier3a = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['19']);
                $tier3asplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['20']);
                $tier3b = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['21']);
                $tier3bsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['22']);
                $tier3c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['23']);
                $tier3csplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['24']);
                $tier3d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['25']);
                $tier3dsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['26']);
                $tier3e = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['27']);
                $tier3esplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['28']);
                $investorrate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['29']);
                $investora = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['30']);
                $investorasplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['31']);
                $investorb = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['32']);
                $investorbsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['33']);
                $investorc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['34']);
                $investorcsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['35']);
                $investord = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['36']);
                $investordsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['37']);
                $investore = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['38']);
                $investoresplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['39']);
                $investorf = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['40']);
                $investorfsplit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $filearray['41']);

                $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM skusearch WHERE skusearchquery='$skusearchquery'"); // Select any rows that match the skusearchquery.
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) { // do this to rows already in the databse that match this query:
                } else {
                    $insert = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO skusearch (skusearchquery, batch, costofgoods, number, fees, lister, listerfee, tier1a, tier1asplit, tier1b, tier1bsplit, tier1c, tier1csplit, tier1d, tier1dsplit, tier1e, tier1esplit, tier2, tier2split, tier3a, tier3asplit, tier3b, tier3bsplit, tier3c, tier3csplit, tier3d, tier3dsplit, tier3e, tier3esplit, investorrate, investora, investorasplit, investorb, investorbsplit, investorc, investorcsplit, investord, investordsplit, investore, investoresplit, investorf, investorfsplit) VALUES ('$skusearchquery', '$batch', $costofgoods, $number, $fees, '$lister', '$listerfee', '$tier1a', '$tier1asplit', '$tier1b', '$tier1bsplit', '$tier1c', '$tier1csplit', '$tier1d', '$tier1dsplit', '$tier1e', '$tier1esplit', '$tier2', '$tier2split', '$tier3a', '$tier3asplit', '$tier3b', '$tier3bsplit', '$tier3c', '$tier3csplit', '$tier3d', '$tier3dsplit', '$tier3e', '$tier3esplit', '$investorrate', '$investora', '$investorasplit', '$investorb', '$investorbsplit', '$investorc', '$investorcsplit', '$investord', '$investordsplit', '$investore', '$investoresplit', '$investorf', '$investorfsplit')") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[And here is the file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Z5tbYBiLkkDA0CV1FEHho3V2jFuQ_GK_3jXpkwgNTY/edit?usp=sharing)  Row 6, the row starting with "JGK", is the row that gets this error. Every other row before it imports fine and the row after it imports fine if I remove the problem row. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance the length of the 1st column is over the table column limit? It looks pretty long

Comment: ^Yup, length limit is what first crossed my mind too. What's the length on that field in the database? Perhaps just set it to 'text' instead of Varchar.

Comment: @apokryfos It is a varchar field set at 50,000 length (for testing purposes). I changed it to text and that didn't fix the issue either. I also tried messing around with the size and setting it to 5,000 and still have the same error.

Comment: By the way as an unrelated thing, if you're escaping everything anyway you can just do `array_map(function ($v) use ($connect) { return mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$v); }, $filearray);` instead of all those individual lines

Comment: Why don't you use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the table from a CSV? If not, you should use a prepared statement instead of escaping every column.

Comment: @apokryfos Even if that's the problem, it won't cause this error, which is about the number of columns in the query, not the size of any value.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: [why `while (!feof($file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Try echoing the `INSERT` query to see what it looks like when it gets the error.