# fgets doesn't read empty lines and spaces properly

Tags: php

I'm having problems with this code:

```
$file = fopen("/home/user/Storage/something/else.java", "r");

while(!feof($file)) {
  echo fgets($file) . "\n";
}

fclose($file);
```

The output of it looks like this:

```
1
2
3
```

While the file is like this:

```
1

  2


 3
```

*(It's just an example, of course the file doesn't look exactly like that)*

---

So, my question is, **why those spaces and blank lines aren't printed?**

I need to display the full file, so *if there's any other method it would help a lot*

Comment: Because you're displaying in a browser that compresses multiple whitespace characters to a single whitespace character? Nothing to do with `feof()`

Comment: Are you aware that HTML strips extra spaces when printed out?  You might want to do a 'view source' and see if those spaces are truly missing. And you look like you are missing `<br>` in the echo, that will cause it to merge to 1 2 3

Comment: Also, see [why `while (!feof($file))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're outputting to an HTML page, whitespace is normally compressed. You can use the `<pre>` tag to display pre-formatted text, and it won't be changed.

```
$file = fopen("/home/user/Storage/something/else.java", "r");
echo '<pre>';
while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
  echo $line . "\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I'm trying to paste the output in a JS variable in this format `<script>var sth = "output";</script>`
I've inspected element and even on the source page there aren't those empty lines or spaces/tabulations

Comment: You must be doing something else, because PHP doesn't remove spaces by itself. Update the question with the actual code.

Comment: I finally fixed by replacing spaces to a 'consistent' group of characterers like the HTML entity and the same for break lines. It works now for me