# PHP Associative array strange behavior

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-key

I am using an associative array which I initialized like this:

```
$img_captions = array();
```

Then, later in the code I am filling it in a while loop with keys and values coming in from a .txt file (every line in that .txt file contains a pair - a string - separated by '|') looking like this:

```
f1.jpg|This is a caption for this specific file
f2.jpg|Yea, also this one
f3.jpg|And this too for sure
...
```

I am filling the associative array with those data like this:

```
if (file_exists($currentdir ."/captions.txt"))
{
    $file_handle = fopen($currentdir ."/captions.txt", "rb");

    while (!feof($file_handle) )
    {
        $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
        $parts = explode('/n', $line_of_text);

        foreach($parts as $img_capts)
        {
            list($img_filename, $img_caption) = explode('|', $img_capts);
            $img_captions[$img_filename] = $img_caption;

        }
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
}
```

When I test that associative array if it actually contains keys and values like:

```
print_r(array_keys($img_captions));
print_r(array_values($img_captions));
```

...I see it contains them as expected, **BUT** when I try to actually use them with direct calling like, let's say for instance:

```
echo $img_captions['f1.jpg'];
```

I get PHP error saying:

> **Notice: Undefined index: f1.jpg in...**

I am clueless what is going on here - can anyone tell, please?

BTW I am using USBWebserver with PHP 5.3.

**UPDATE 1:** so by better exploring the output of the 'print_r(array_keys($img_captions));' inside Chrome (F12 key) I noticed something strange - **THE FIRST LINE OF '[0] => f1.jpg' LOOKS VISUALLY VERY WEIRD** tho it looks normal when displayed as print_r() output on the site, I noticed it actually in fact is coded like this in webpage source (F12):

```
Array
(
    [0] => &#65279;f1.jpg
    [1] => f2.jpg
    [2] => f3.jpg
    [3] => f4.jpg
    [4] => f5.jpg
    [5] => f6.jpg
    [6] => f7.jpg
    [7] => f8.jpg
    [8] => f9.jpg
    [9] => f10.jpg
)
```

So when I tested anything else than the 1. line it works OK. I tryed to delete completely the file and re-write it once again but still the same occurs...

> **DISCLAIMER** Guys, just to clarify things more properly: THIS IS NOT MY ORIGINAL CODE (that is 'done completely by me'), it is
>   actually a **MiniGal Nano** PHP photogalery I had just make to suit my
>   needs but those specific parts we are talking about are **FROM THE
>   ORIGINAL AUTHOR**

Comment: what's the output of `print_r(array_keys($img_captions));`?

Comment: Several problems with your code: [Don't use `while (!feof($file_handle))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything). `'/n'` should be `"\n"` (wrong quotes, wrong slash).

Comment: `'/n'` will not explode on newlines.  Try using `file()`

Comment: Use `file()` with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option.

Comment: There's no need to explode on newline in the first place, since `fgets()` only reads one line.

Comment: Don't use `rb` mode if you're reading text, use `r`.

Comment: I'll bet the actual problem is that there's spaces before or after the filename fields in the file.

Comment: If the problem does turn out to be extra whitespace in the filenames, and you want to use the code as-is, then I guess the solution is to modify the file to remove the spaces.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I updated my post, please look it up - there is now that output you want

Comment: @errerr  check my answer once. A very short and easy solution given. Try that

Comment: @AlivetoDie OK, gonna try it now...

Comment: I think the problem most probably is the first line in the txt file which always get started with those strange signs whatever I do: I can delete it and write again - still the same, I can remove the first line so the 2nd is now the 1st one - still the same...I begin to think that the Windows NotePad is adding something to the beginning of the 1st line...I will try .log instead of .txt

Comment: That's the HTML entity for a BYTE ORDER MARK or BOM, save your file with no BOM in whatever editor you're using. Or it's getting there some other way.

Comment: @AbraCadaver oh, thanx for letting me know - I did not know that (anyway I already switched to .log file instead of .txt as I do not have this problem there at all)

Comment: @AbraCadaver although I do not need it anymore I just tested your solution anyway - it works! So if you would post this answer as separate reply I would sign it as the solution to this cos this way I cannot do that... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I realize there is something wrong with my `.txt` file itself as it:-

*ALWAYS PUT SOME STRANGE SIGNS IN FRONT OF THE 1st LINE WHATEVER I DO IT WAS ALWAYS THERE EVEN WITH THE NEW FILE CREATED FROM SCRATCH (although those are UNVISIBLE unless seen as a source code on a webpage!!!)*

So I decided to test it in another format, this time .log file and all of a sudden everything works just fine.

I do not know if it is just my local problem of some sort (most probably is) or something else I am not aware of.

***But my solution*** to this was changing the file type holding the string pairs (.txt => .log) which solved this 'problem' for me.

Some ***other possible solution*** to this as @AbraCadaver said:

> (Those strange signs: [0] => &#65279;f1.jpg) That's the HTML entity for a BYTE ORDER MARK or BOM, save your file
>   with no BOM in whatever editor you're using.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) along wth  [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Your code becomes short, readable and easy to understand.

```
$parts= file('your text file url', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$img_captions = [];
foreach($parts as $img_capts){
    list($img_filename, $img_caption) = explode('|', $img_capts);
    $img_captions[trim(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$img_filename))] = trim(preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$img_caption));
}
print_r($img_captions);
```

Comment: `trim()` is probably the solution he's missing.

Comment: @Barmar  i thought exactly same, but i have a better idea than OP's code. so i posted that idea along with `trim()`