# PHP find count of csv file records

Tags: php, csv

Hello I have written a code in php to read from a csv file, print it and count the number of lines. Now I also need to find the number of records. Can someone help me out? Thank you!

```
<?php
$c =0;
$fp = fopen("teksti.csv","r");

while(!feof($fp)){
    $content = fgets($fp);
    print_r ($content);
    if($content)   
        $c++;
}

 fclose($fp);
 echo $c;?>
```

Comment: What defines a record? A row?

Comment: [why `while(!feof($fp))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: A cell. I have already counted the rows. Now I need to count every cell.

Comment: `count($content)`

Comment: Use `fgetcsv()` instead of `fgets()`. Then use `count($content)` to get the number of columns in the row.

Comment: Well, a little more than that @splash58 because you have to add the content of the rows or multiply the number of rows times the content count.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Records are usually rows, not cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fgetcsv()` instead of `fgets()`. This will parse the row into fields and return an array. Then you can use `count()` to get the number of elements, and add this to a total.

```
<?php
$rows = 0;
$cells = 0;
$fp = fopen("teksti.csv","r");

while($content = fgetcsv($fp)){
    print_r ($content);
    $rows++;
    $cells += count($content);
}

fclose($fp);
echo "Total rows = $rows, total cells = $cells";
?>
```