# How do I get the maximum number of fields from all rows in a csv or txt file?

Tags: php

I need to find a line with the maximum number of fields from a **LARGE** csv and/or txt file.

**[DEMO](https://rssbot.ru/parser/file.php)**

Maybe **fgetcsv** php

This is necessary in order to then display the required number of **select** in the form.

Example:

name,name2,name3

name,name2,name3

name,name2,name3,name4

name,name2,name3

name,name2,name3,name4,name5

name,name2,name3

name,name2,name3

How do I get 5 from the example above?

Incorrect result in the table:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgka0.png)

My code:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters, $string) {
$ready  = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
$launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
return $launch;
}


<table>
<tr>';


$i = 0; //начальное значение


while ((($i <= 0) and $text = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== false) {

$i++;

$text = str_replace('"', '', $text);

$exploded = multiexplode (array(",", ";", "|"), $text);

foreach($exploded as $item){

$item = trim ($item);

if(isset($item) && $item !== '')  {  

echo '
<th>
<select name="select2">
    <option selected="selected">Выберите поле</option>
    <option value="name">Имя</option>
    <option value="phone">Телефон</option>
    <option value="data">Дата рождения</option>
    <option value="create">+ Создать новое поле</option>
</select>
</th>';

}

}
print '
</tr>';

}
```

I count the maximum number of fields in the first line, but I don't know how to count the maximum number of fields in the entire file.

Comment: You should use `fgetcsv`, otherwise this will fail if one of the field values ever contains the delimiter character. And you of course need to loop over all the data once and find the row with the most fields first, you can not start creating the output in the initial loop over the data, that needs a second one.

Comment: I can't sort through all the rows and find the row with the maximum number of fields :(

Comment: Why not, what is the actual problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. It is not possible to determine the maximum number of fields in all rows.

Comment: Initialize a variable `$maxFields = 0;` or something, before the loop. Then inside the loop, get the number of fields in the current row - and if that is greater than the current value of `$maxFields`, then you set that as the new value for `$maxFields`. (Or use the `max` function.)

Comment: It became clearer. I.e. I need to store the maximum number of fields somewhere and constantly compare it with the current one, right?

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what I just said.

Comment: Can these fields contain `,` that is not treated as separator? E.g. `"field,field", "field2"`

Comment: I can't know in advance what the user will upload. It is not known whether there will be comma separators or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [spout](https://github.com/box/spout) to read large CSV files as fast, document [LINK](https://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/) .

So you can count CSV file records as native like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816688/php-find-count-of-csv-file-records).