# How to check if PHP download was canceled?

Tags: php, download

I need to log total downloads of an specific file. Download function is working fine, but can't define if user canceled (clicking "cancel" on browser dialog) or if connection was aborted latter.
I understand it's not simple to know when a file download was finished, so I'm trying to get this by two ways. None works:

1. **Get total bytes sent, latter I will compare it with total file size:** this way $bytes_sent var always is set with total file size, no matter if user click cancel button of download dialog or if cancel download process latter.
2. **Trigger connection_aborted() function:** Have not found the way this function happen and define my session var...

(I'm not shure if the fact Im working with sessions is relevant).

I appreciate your help :)

```
<?php
if(is_file($filepath)){
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "r");

    header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filepath).";");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $name);

    while(!feof($handle)){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
        print $data;
        $_SESSION['download'] = 'Successful download';
        //Always is set as total file lenght, even when cancel a large file download before it finish:
        bytes_sent = ftell($handle);
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        //Can't trigger connection aborted, in any case:
        if(connection_aborted()){
            $_SESSION['download'] = 'Canceled download';
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Version 5.3.29

Comment: Unrelated to the question: [Why `while (!feof($handle))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: `ftell()` is always be the end of the file, since you're reading the entire file with `fread($handle, filesize($filepath)`. An error while printing it doesn't undo the read, that would be time travel.

Comment: You need to read the file in small chunks in a loop.

Comment: Yes, I have considered it. Any suggestions or references on how to do it?

Comment: You mean like in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file in small chunks, rather than reading it all in at once.

```
$chunk_size = 1000;
ignore_user_abort();
$canceled = false;
while ($chunk = fread($handle, $chunk_size)) {
    print $chunk;
    ob_flush();
    $bytes_sent += strlen($chunk);
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        $canceled = true;
        break;
    }
}
$_SESSION['download'] = $canceled ? "Download canceled" : "Download successful";
```

Comment: Thanks. This way I'm still getting $bytes_sent as total file size, even before download start, and $canceled as false. Seems like while loop is finished before accept download...

Comment: the problem may be that the webserver is buffering the output, so the script can send all the data before it's notified of the abort.