# Mysql returning highest id value while not requested in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP script is returning the Mysql value with the highest ID, not the requested ID:

```
 <?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '(Password)', 'web');
#THE 'userEmail' variable is from a script above not displayed on here
$email = $row['userEmail'];
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email'");

echo "<center><table border='1'>

    <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Active?</th>
    <th>Add Account</th>
    <th>Delete Account</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $userName = $row['username'];
    $passWord = $row['password'];
    $addId = $row['id'];
    $deleteId = $row['id'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['activeStatus'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=home.php?add=$addId>Add Account</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=home.php?delete=$deleteId>Delete Account</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></center>";

if( isset($_GET['delete']) ) {  
    $deleteId = $_GET['delete'];
    $delete = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $deleteId";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $delete);
    deleteLineInFile("/var/www/html/table-users.txt","'$userName'");
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record";
    }
}

if( isset($_GET['add']) ) {  
    $addId = $_GET['add'];
    $add = "(Too long to display)";

    echo("$userName, $passWord"); 

    file_put_contents("/var/www/html/directory/$addId.xml", $add);
    header("Location: directory/$addId.xml");

}

function deleteLineInFile($file,$string)
{
    $i=0;$array=array();

    $read = fopen($file, "r") or die("can't open the file");
    while(!feof($read)) {
        $array[$i] = fgets($read);  
        ++$i;
    }
    fclose($read);

    $write = fopen($file, "w") or die("can't open the file");
    foreach($array as $a) {
        if(!strstr($a,$string)) fwrite($write,$a);
    }
    fclose($write);
}
?>
```

Every time I try to get the ID, it only displays the id with the highest value. I don't know what the problem is. I think it is a problem with the row because the `$userName = $row['username'];` and `$passWord = $row['password'];` lines are stored in the loop. I noticed that it will pick up the id for the `$_GET` variable correctly, but it won't for the `$row` variable. Could someone help me figure out this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by the requested ID? Do you mean the requested email in `$row['userEmail']`?

Comment: Your assessment is correct, the last value in the recordset will be the one stored in `$addId` and `$deleteId`, since you're iterating over them and overwriting the previous value. What is your desired result?

Comment: [why `while(!feof($read))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: @fyrye He's not using those variables in the later code, he sets them from `$_GET` parameters. In the loop they're just used to create the parameters in the `href`

Comment: Please show your entire script, as you're using `$row['email']` then overwriting `$row` with a second query against the email. This looks like a nested query that of which we can not determine. If it is a nested query, I suggest using a `JOIN`instead.

Comment: @Barmar I was using `$addId` as the id associated with the `$userName` and `$passWord` variables being used in the `if (isset($_GET['add']))` condition, as assessed by the OP in the question.

Comment: I didn't mention that there is a $userName and $passWord variable in the $add variable string. And that's where it is messing up, as well as the `deleteLineInFile` function called from `isset($_GET['delete'])`

Comment: @GrantGordinier Your question included debug code `echo("$userName, $passWord"); ` in your `isset($_GET['add'])`, so it is assumed to be needed there. While `$userName` is used in the `isset($_GET['delete'])`. The [answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003351/1144627) explains the issue and resolves it for both actions, unless there is additional logic in the portions of code you excluded from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted, `$userName` and `$password` don't contain the info for the submitted ID, they contain the last value from the `while` loop. You need to do a database query to look up the corresponding username.

```
if( isset($_GET['add']) ) {  
    $addId = $_GET['add'];
    $add = "(Too long to display)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT username, password FROM table WHERE id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $addId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userName, $passWord);
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo("$userName, $passWord"); 

        file_put_contents("/var/www/html/directory/$addId.xml", $add);
        header("Location: directory/$addId.xml");
    } else {
        die("User ID $addId not found");
    }
}
```

I've also shown how to use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection. You should use this method everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, this PHP modification did not work.

Comment: Nothing has changed, it is doing the exact same thing from when I asked this question.

Comment: You never answered my question. What do you mean by "Every time I try to get the ID"? Which part of the code is trying to get the ID? The `while` loop puts a different ID in every link. Clicking on a link adds or deletes that ID.

Comment: The Username and Password variable echo only the most recently added row, and not the requested row.

Comment: There's no way my code could do that. Your code has that problem because you set the variables in the `while` loop, so at the end of the loop they contain the values from the last row of the query.

Comment: I need it to be in the `while` loop because the $row variable won't work outside of the `while` loop. Is there another way?

Comment: There's no problem with that. But you can't expect the variable AFTER the loop to contain a specific row, the loop processes all the rows. That's why my answer does a new query to get the row of the selected ID.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar and I noted, your `$userName` and `$passWord` variables are being overwritten by the `while` loop. As such the `ID` specified in `$_GET['add']` and `$_GET['delete']` requests will not be associated with the correct `$userName`.

In order to resolve the issue, you must lookup the user details by the `ID` associated with the desired `add` or `delete` `$_GET` request.

*Note: the use of the object oriented `mysqli` syntax is used below, as it is less verbose and personally easier for me to read.*

```
<?php
#/var/www/html/home.php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '(Password)', 'web');

/* ensure an expected action is requested and determine associated ID */
$actionId = null;
if (!empty($_GET['add'])) {
    $actionId = $_GET['add'];
} elseif (!empty($_GET['delete'])) {
    $actionId = $_GET['delete'];
}

/* execute action before outputting user table (use strict comparison operator !==) */
if (null !== $actionId) {
    /* an action was specified - retrieve the associated user details from the database */
    if (!$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username, password FROM table WHERE id = ?')) {
        die('Unable to retrieve user details.');
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $actionId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userName, $passWord);
    if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
        die('Unknown user specified');
    }

    /* execute desired add action */
    if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
        # debug code prevents redirect
        die("$userName, $passWord");

        $add = '(Too long to display)';
        /* use __DIR__ as opposed to full path in case you ever move hosts */
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/directory/$actionId.xml", $add);
        header("Location: directory/$actionId.xml");
        exit;
    }

    /* execute desired delete action */
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        if (!$stmtDelete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?')) {
            die('Error updating record');
        }
        $stmtDelete->bind_param('s', $actionId);
        if (!$result = $stmtDelete->execute()) {
            die('Error updating record');
        }

        /*
         * only check file if it was deleted from the database successfully
         * use __DIR__ as opposed to full path in case you ever move hosts
         */
        deleteLineInFile(__DIR__ . '/table-users.txt', "'$userName'");

        # debug code prevents redirect
        die('Record updated successfully');

        header('Location: home.php');
        exit;
    }
}

/*
 * this is where <html> should start unless you utilize output buffering
 * output the HTML and your table data after your request action, to ensure the redirects occur
 */
$email = $row['userEmail']; //retrieved from somewhere else
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, username, password, activeStatus FROM table WHERE email = ?')) {
    die('Unable to retrieve account list');
}
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->bind_result($userId, $userName, $passWord, $activeStatus);

echo "<center><table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Active?</th>
    <th>Add Account</th>
    <th>Delete Account</th>
    </tr>";

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //always escape user supplied values being output to HTML
    $userName = htmlentities($userName, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    $passWord = htmlentities($passWord, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    $activeStatus = htmlentities($activeStatus, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $userName . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $passWord . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $activeStatus . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='home.php?add=" . $userId . "'>Add Account</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='home.php?delete=" . $userId . "'>Delete Account</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></center>";
```

I also suggest converting your HTML attributes from using single quote `'` to using double quote `"`, to ensure compatibility and uniformity with any other library you may use.