# Two arrays are getting created when trying to fetch array values using a string match in php

Tags: php, arrays

In below code i have created an array which contains the value which matches some particular string pattern. In this array, i am trying to fetch only those values of the array which has POST keyword and save it in another array. It should return 1 array of size 2. However, when i am trying to do so, it is resulting in creation of two arrays. One array of size 1 and another array of size 2. However i want just one array. Can someone please guide where i am wrong.

```
$fh = fopen("website-audit.2018.08.30.log","r");
$started = false;
while (!feof($fh)) {
  $line = fgets($fh);
  if($started) {
    $temp .= $line;
    if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
      $started = false;
      $array[] = $temp;
    }
  }
  if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
    $started = true;
    $temp = $line;
  }
}
fclose($fh);


$keyword = 'POST';
foreach($array as $index){
    if (strpos($index, $keyword) !== FALSE){
        $val = array($index);
        var_dump($val);
    }   
}
```

Comment: [why `while(!feof($fh))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Hi again, can u please post what the output is?

Comment: I don't see how you're ever getting an array of size 2 in this code. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Why did you try to edit my answer? If you need to clarify, you should edit the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new array each time through the loop, instead of adding to an array.

```
$val = array();
foreach ($array as $index) {
    if (strpos($index, $keyword) !== false) {
        $val[] = $index;
    }
}
var_dump($val);
```

You can also use `array_filter()`:

```
$val = array_filter($array, function($index) use ($keyword) {
    return strpos($index, $keyword) !== false;
});
```

Or you can do this in the loop that reads from the file, instead of a separate loop

```
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
 if($started) {
    $temp .= $line;
    if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
      $started = false;
      $array[] = $temp;
      if (strpos($temp, $keyword) !== false) {
        $val[] = $temp;
      }
    }
  }
  if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
    $started = true;
    $temp = $line;
  }
}
```