# How to delete two first lines in txt using PHP

Tags: php

For example I have data:

```
File generated by system automatically...
9 rows selected.

Heber,Camrynborough,26728,Home Health Aide
Modesto,West Janet,15152-2683,Software Engineer
Dante,East Chanel,74689-6886,Entertainment Attendant
Nolan,Murphyville,32561-8079,Credit Authorizer
Jovany,O'Reillyton,44371,Medical Assistant
Jaeden,Greenfort,06179-1759,School Social Worker
Efrain,West Blairborough,11282-0496,Electronic Drafter
Travon,South Tatum,76603-0822,Manufactured Building Installer
Agustina,North Gertrudeland,18950,Health Services Manager
```

and simple php code to import data into mysql

```
$open = fopen('employee-data.txt','r');

while (!feof($open)) 
{
    $getTextLine = fgets($open);
    $explodeLine = explode(",",$getTextLine);

    list($name,$city,$postcode,$job_title) = $explodeLine;

    $qry = "insert into empoyee_details (name, city,postcode,job_title) values('".$name."','".$city."','".$postcode."','".$job_title."')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
}

fclose($open);
```

It works fine, but problem is on start read file, because file contains three useless lines (two with text and last one is empty). How can I delete lines before start import data into mysql?

Comment: *file contains three useless lines* How you detect it?

Comment: My file txt at the beginning contains three useless lines always. I looking for solution to skip first three lines, delete three lines or start import data from 4 line.

Comment: Use regex like `$newStr = preg_replace("/^([^\n]+\n){3}/", "", $str)`

Comment: how about just testing that size of $explodeLine is 3? if not log it and continue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening the file, call `fgets()` 3 times to skip over those lines.

```
$open = fopen('employee-data.txt','r');
# skip heading lines.
fgets($open);
fgets($open);
fgets($open);
```

Also, you shouldn't use `while (!feof($open))`, see [PHP - while loop (!feof()) isn't outputting/showing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Use:

```
while ($explodedLine = fgetcsv($open)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not tested but `fgetcsv` might give you an empty array for the blank line and empty array is falsy.

Comment: I assumed that the only blank line is the one at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Use a variable that counts the lines and skip the cycle if its value is lower than the number of lines to skip.

```
$row = 0;
while (!feof($open)) {
    $getTextLine = fgets($open);

    if ($row++ < 3)
        continue;

    // ...
}
```