# Email piping works but bounce email is sent

Tags: php, email, pipe

I'm working on a script that pipes email messages to a database. 
I have the script working, but it sends a bounce email too.

Here is the bounce message:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  pipe to |/home/montanah/public_html/admin/getmail.php
    generated by test@domain.com

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/montanah/public_html/admin/getmail.php
       generated by test@domain.com ------
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require("db.php");
$email_msg = ''; // the content of the email that is being piped
// open a handle to the email
$fh = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
// read through the email until the end
while (!feof($fh)){
    $email_msg .= fread($fh, 1024);
}
fclose($fh); 
MDB::insert("res_recieved_mail", array("time"=>time(), "body"=>$email_msg, "status"=>1)); 
exit(0);
```

I have tried all of the following:
ending with exit(0);, not ending with exit. return null;, ending with ?>
I've CHMODDED 0700, 0755, 0777
I have made sure there are no blank lines, in either my script, or db.php
I've made sure my editor (notepad++) is using unix new lines not windows, and I am uploading as ASCII not binary.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might not be related, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything

Comment: Why do you use `error_reporting(0)`? When you're debugging, use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: I have the error_reporting(0) to turn off any errors that might be popping up. The script works, it uploads any emails piped to it into a database. I just don't want people emailing that address to get a bounce message.

Comment: You might want to ask in [unix.se] to find out what causes your mailer to generate that bounce message. Also, you should say what mail software you're using (sendmail, postfix, etc.) and how you have mail for the user configured to pipe to the script.