# How to modify json to validate it?

Tags: php, json

I am downloading some json and merging them, but while doing that it creates a string like below,

```
    }
][
    {
```

I'd like to replace that with a comma in order to have a valid json

I tried something like this but it's not working:

```
$datas = array();
$json = str_replace("][",",", $datas);
$json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

If I can manage to do that I'd use the same to replace columns name (I'm actually building this json from a csv) if possible.

**UPDATE**

To clarify I have multiple csv(s) from which I am then building a single json

**FULL CODE**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array("04-12-2020",
    "04-13-2020",
    "04-14-2020",
    "04-15-2020",
    "04-16-2020",
    "04-17-2020",
    "04-18-2020",
    "04-19-2020",
    "04-20-2020",
    "04-21-2020",
    "04-22-2020",
    "04-23-2020",
    "04-24-2020",
    "04-25-2020",
    "04-26-2020",
    "04-27-2020",
    "04-28-2020",
    "04-29-2020",
    "04-30-2020",
    "05-01-2020",
    "05-02-2020",
    "05-03-2020",
    "05-04-2020",
    "05-05-2020",
    "05-06-2020",
    "05-07-2020",
    "05-08-2020",
    "05-09-2020",
);

foreach($arr as $date) {

    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/".$date.".csv";

    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {

        $csvs = [];
        while(! feof($handle)) {
            $csvs[] = fgetcsv($handle);
        }
        $datas = [];
        $column_names = [];
        foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
            $column_names[] = $single_csv;
        }
        foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
            if ($key === 0) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
                $datas[$key-1][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
            }
        }
        $json = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        fclose($handle);
        print_r($json);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan as i said in the question I am building the json from csvs, so each set is a csv, then I merge but I get that issue as per the question

Comment: Don't process the JSON, process the arrays directly.

Comment: @rob.m yeah, took me to realize you have **multiple** JSONs and you're merging them.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure who to get the json later

Comment: @rob.m ... `array_merge` and than you know the drill: `json_encode` the merged array

Comment: You shouldn't put multiple JSON in a single file, it's impossible to reliably detect where the ends are. You should make it a single JSON with an array of all the objects.

Comment: @Barmar I think is actually whaat I meant but didn't explain it well, this is the data I get https://jikuhealth.com/wp-content/themes/JikuHealth/scripts/covid-19_us_data.php and it needs to become a single valid json

Comment: If you call `json_encode()` on that array it will be a single valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar it's what I thought too but it is giving the double ] as per the question

Comment: Then the problem is with the code that's filling in `$datas`. Show how you're doing that.

Comment: @Barmar updated the question with the full code

Comment: Not related to the problem, but see [why `while (!feof($handle))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `json_encode()` inside the loop. Initialize `$datas` outside the loop, and encode it after the loop.

```
$datas = [];

foreach($arr as $date) {
    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/".$date.".csv";

    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvs = [];
        while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $csvs[] = $row;
        }
        $column_names = [];
        // Use header line to get array keys
        foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
            $column_names[] = $single_csv;
        }
        array_shift($csvs); // remove header line
        foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
            $new_data = [];
            foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
                $new_data[$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
            }
            $datas[] = $new_data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: breaks here `$csvs[] = ;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, also for that `feof` too just for the sake of it, on the json can we change some keys before to create the actual json? Like "Last_Update" > "date" or "Lat" as "lat", I'm a super php boy, I'd do that in js later on but I was wondering if that could be done here

Comment: `if ($single_csv == "Last_Update") { $single_csv = "date"; }`

Comment: If you know the expected order of the columns and the keys you want to use for them, you could just predefine an array `$column_names = ["date", "lat", "long", ...];` and use those instead of the headings from the file.

Comment: I guess I can then, the csvs are always the same

Comment: hey man, I just noticed this is only grabbibg the last csv tho, not all of them

Comment: Make sure `$datas = [];` is before the `for` loop, not inside it.

Comment: it's like re writing $datas

Comment: Got the answer, this answer is wrong then https://stackoverflow.com/a/61716728/1018804

Comment: The problem is using `$datas[$key]` in the loop, because `$key` starts over at 0 for each file. It's better to push into the array.

Comment: it's broken here $csvs[] = ;

Comment: That's the same as the earlier error, because I went back to my other window.