# Loop only grabbing last obj

Tags: php

I'm runnign this:

```
$arr = array("04-12-2020",
    "04-13-2020",
    "04-14-2020",
    "04-15-2020",
    "04-16-2020",
    "04-17-2020",
    "04-18-2020",
    "04-19-2020",
    "04-20-2020",
    "04-21-2020",
    "04-22-2020",
    "04-23-2020",
    "04-24-2020",
    "04-25-2020",
    "04-26-2020",
    "04-27-2020",
    "04-28-2020",
    "04-29-2020",
    "04-30-2020",
    "05-01-2020",
    "05-02-2020",
    "05-03-2020",
    "05-04-2020",
    "05-05-2020",
    "05-06-2020",
    "05-07-2020",
    "05-08-2020",
    "05-09-2020"
);

$datas = [];

foreach($arr as $date) {
    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/".$date.".csv";

    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvs = [];
        while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $csvs[] = $row;
        }
        $column_names = [];
        // Use header line to get array keys
        foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
            $column_names[] = $single_csv;
        }
        array_shift($csvs); // remove header line
        foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
            foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
                $datas[$key][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

but when I do:

```
print_r($json);
```

I only get the last csv data, while I should see all of them in it

Comment: So, `$datas[$key][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];` overwrites each column every time, isn't it?

Comment: @u_mulder yes, how would I fix it tho? I'm not sure where to put it

Comment: `$datas[$key][$column_name][] = $csv[$column_key];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving $datas anywhere before the next iteration of the loop, so it gets overwritten on every iteration.

```
$json = [];

foreach($arr as $date) {
    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/".$date.".csv";

    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvs = [];
        while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $csvs[] = $row;
        }
        $column_names = [];
        // Use header line to get array keys
        foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
            $column_names[] = $single_csv;
        }
        array_shift($csvs); // remove header line
        foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
            foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
                $datas[$key][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
            }
        }
        $json[] = json_encode($datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

print_r($json);
```