# Why the error message is not showing in my PHP code after adding CSS?

Tags: php, css, comments

I've wrote this code for a comment section for my website. But that was suppose to show error message beside the '*' sign when anyone types in incorrect email or empty comment. It was doing good, but after I've added the CSS styles it is not working.

I'm reading the input and passing that to PHP. After PHP checks that, I save that to a comment folder. Or else if the format is wrong, I give an error message. But now the error message is not showing for some reason.

Link of the code running in a host https://cryptocrack.000webhostapp.com/comment/test/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="title">
            <h2>Leave a comment</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="contact-form">
            <div class="input-fields">
               <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
               <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="input" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                  <br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="msg">
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comment"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $commentErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cm">
         <div class="tl">
            <h1>Comments</h1>
         </div>
         <br><br>
         <?php
            // define variables and set to empty values
            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
            
            $nameErr = $emailErr = $commentErr = "";
            $name = $email = $comment = "";
            
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
              if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                $nameErr = "Name is required";
              } else {
                $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                }
              }
              
              if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
              } else {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                  $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                }
              }
            
              if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
                $commentErr = "Comment is required";
              } else {
                $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
              }
                
                if($nameErr==""&&$emailErr==""&&$commentErr==""){
                    $cd=date("d.m.Y l h:i:s a");
                    $d=(string)mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
                    $cf = fopen(getcwd()."/comments/".$d.".txt", "w");
                    fwrite($cf, $name."\n");
                    fwrite($cf, $cd."\n");
                    fwrite($cf, $email."\n");
                    fwrite($cf, $comment);
                    fclose($cf);
                }
                
            }
            
            function test_input($data) {
              $data = trim($data);
              $data = stripslashes($data);
              $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
              return $data;
            }
            
            $dir=getcwd()."/comments/";
            $cm = scandir($dir,1);
            $len = count($cm)-2;
            
            for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
                $f=fopen($dir.$cm[$i],"r");
                echo "<div class=\"name\">" .fgets($f)."</div><div class=\"date\">".fgets($f)."</div><div class=\"email\">".fgets($f)."</div><br>";
                while(!feof($f)){
                    echo fgets($f)."<br>";
                }
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
            
            ?>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no CSS in the code you posted.

Comment: You're echoing `$nameErr` and `$emailErr` before you set them.

Comment: Unrelated: [why `while (!feof($f))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar dude. It worked! I'm saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($nameErr)){ echo $nameErr; } ?>
```

use that instead of

```
 <?php echo $nameErr;?>
```

You get error cause the variables are not defined.

Comment: still no luck :'(