# Issue with searching for a word from 2 differents text files

Tags: php

I've been pulling my hair for the couple last hours, I can't figure this out, all I'm trying to do is to take 1 line from list.txt file then search for a match in source.txt file, here is my code

```
<?php

//Let's open the file

$list = @fopen("files/list.txt", "r");
$source = @fopen("files/source.txt", "r");


//I'm calculating number of lines in list.txt

$no_of_lines = count(file('files/list.txt'));

//I created 2 loops
//The first loop is to repeat the process based on the total number of lines in list.txt
//the second loop is the extract only 1 entry from the list.txt and search for a match in source.txt

    for ($x=1; $x <= $no_of_lines ; $x++) { 
        for ($i=1; $i <= 1 ; $i++) { 
            $getLine = fgets($list);
            $matches = array();
            if ($source)
            {
                while (!feof($source))
                {
                    $buffer = fgets($source);
                    if(strpos($source, $getLine) !== FALSE)
                        $matches[] = $buffer;
                }
                fclose($source);
            }
                }
    }

    //show results:
    
    print_r($matches);
```

+source.txt has numbers from 1 to 100, each number in a separate line.
+list.txt has these numbers:

```
5
20000
1000000
87456


Current Error: Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\laragon\www\SearchFind\test2.php on line 26
```

I've tried many stackexchange solutions but nothing worked out.

Comment: [why `while (!feof($source))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: `strpos($source, $getLine)` - why do you pass a resource (result of fopen) into that function?

Comment: I think you mean `strpos($buffer, $getLine)`

Comment: The string returned by `fgets()` ends with a newline. You need to remove that if you want to match it in part of another string.

Comment: sorry to confuse you guys, I put the while in order to have search in similar time when the entry from list.txt is selected. I think I'm wrong, so how this should be?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to get 1 entry from list.txt and scan source.txt to search for a match

Comment: You need to reopen `$source` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There's no need to count the lines in `list.txt` first. Just loop calling `fgets()` until you get to the end of the file.
- You need to initialize the `$matches` array before the loop. Otherwise you clear it out before searching for each number, and the final value will just be the matches for the last number in `list.txt`.
- You need to reopen `source.txt` each time through the outer loop so you can read from it again.
- You should be searching `$buffer` in the `strpos()` call, not `$source` (that's the reason for the error you're getting).
- Don't use `while (!feof($source))`. Use `while ($buffer = fgets($source))`. `fgets()` returns `FALSE` when you get to the end of the file.
- You need to use `rtrim($getLine)` and `rtrim($buffer) to remove the newline at the end of the line, so you're just searching for the number.
- `for ($i=1; $i <= 1 ; $i++)` serves no purpose at all. It just loops one time, which is the same as not looping at all.
- If you want to match the whole line, not just look for a substring, use `===` to compare `$getLine` and `$buffer`, not `strpos()`.

```
<?php
//Let's open the file
$list = fopen("list.txt", "r");
$matches = array();

if ($list) {
    while ($getLine = fgets($list)) {
        $getLine = rtrim($getLine); // remove newline
        $source = fopen("source.txt", "r");
        if ($source)
        {
            while ($buffer = fgets($source)) {
                $buffer = rtrim($buffer);
                if($buffer === $getLine)
                    $matches[] = $buffer;
            }
            fclose($source);
        }
    }
}
//show results:
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it fast and I got the following result
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 15 [2] => 25 [3] => 35 [4] => 45 [5] => 50 [6] => 51 [7] => 52 [8] => 53 [9] => 54 [10] => 55 [11] => 56 [12] => 57 [13] => 58 [14] => 59 [15] => 65 [16] => 75 [17] => 85 [18] => 95 )

I'm not sure where all those numbers came from as my list doesn't specify all of those, only number 5 which should be a match.

Comment: `strpos()` looks for `$getLine` anywhere in `$buffer`. So if `$getLine` is `5` it will match `50`, `25`, `155`, etc.

Comment: If you don't want to search like this, just use `if ($buffer === $getLine)`

Comment: Yes, of course. Why did you use `strpos()` if you didn't want to search for it anywhere?

Comment: Correct, however I'm getting Warning: fgets(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource
Array ( )

Comment: I don't have line numbers, which one is that?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it using `===` instead of `strpos()`. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to say this but my browser tab keeps loading with no result, it's like a loop.

Comment: I just ran it from the CLI, not a browser.

Comment: Yeah, I did also php -f file.php with no result, something is missing i guess

Comment: I figured it out, I can't thank you enough, I really appreciate your help and your time, God Bless you :)

Comment: Just a quick question, if for example the number from the text file is listed as 1 space 1, with the === it will not be considered identical, how to solve this one?

Comment: Why would you have a space in the middle of the number? You could remove all the spaces with `str_replace()`.

Comment: it's because i have the number phone space name, so if i remove the space it will still not be matched

Comment: If you have names in the text, then it won't be an exact match. You really need to add these details to the question, it's impossible to answer when you leave out important details.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need to do is split each line into words, then check whether any of the words match the number in `lists.txt`. Or maybe you only want to check a specific field. You could also use `fgetcsv()` to split it into fields while you're reading.

Comment: "It sounds like what you really need to do is split each line into words, then check whether any of the words match the number in lists.txt" probably  that's the idea so even if there is a single word in that line with other words, i want that to be matched

Comment: `if (in_array($getLine, explode(' ', $buffer)))`

Comment: PHP has plenty of utility functions for processing strings. You need to study them and learn to use them. You can't program by coming to the Internet and asking for code every time you get lost.

Comment: I agree, thank you for being patient with me, i really appreciate your efforts.