# Can PHP wait when you send a request for server?

Tags: php

Send a request to the server but you must wait until the request is completed. Note I use Post Request on the PHP code waiting until the request is completed then the rest

```
then(function () {
    // You can write operations here..
})
```

Or

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = Amp\ReactAdapter\ReactAdapter::get();
$loop ->addtimer(1, function(){
    $file = fopen("amar.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($file)) {
        echo fgets($file). "<br>". " ";

    }

    echo " After Reading File ". "<br>". " ";
});

echo " After Loop Time". "<br>". " ";

$loop->run();
?>
```

Comment: PHP is synchronous by default. So, it does wait!

Comment: Aside: [why `while (!feof($file))` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What is the `then()` stuff at the top, how does it relate to PHP? And where is the MySQL code?

Comment: Javascript promises are always async. That's why you have a callback. You could use `await doTheRequest();` and make doTheRquest() an async function.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be more about non-blocking file reading rather than asynchronous requests. I don't see how you're making the request to the server.

However, if you're making an HTTP request using something like `file_get_contents()` or `curl`, by default, the code will wait for the response before continuing execution.