# PHP 8.1 Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in array construction

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, warnings, php-8.1

I have a problem with the construction of an array which produces this error in PHP 8.1:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sito3\xlsx.php on line 250

I eliminated the warning but I would like to understand how to get rid of it cleanly.

This is my function:

```
function dividi_nome_cognome(string $stringa): array 
{
    if (str_word_count($stringa, 1) === 2) {
        // only one separator " "
        return trim(explode(" ", $stringa));
    } else {
        // more than one separator
        return [
            trim(substr($stringa, 0, strrpos($stringa, " "))),
            trim(substr($stringa, strrpos($stringa, " "))),
        ];
    }
}
```

and the other function:

```
function csvToArray($csvFile,$separatore){
    
    $file_to_read = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    
    while (!feof($file_to_read) ) {     
        $lines[] = fgetcsv($file_to_read, 1000, $separatore);       
    }
    
    fclose($file_to_read);
    return $lines;
}
```

I'm trying to build an array from a .csv file with separator ","

```
$arr_csv = csvToArray($nome_file_csv,',');
for($c=0; $c< count($arr_csv ); $c++){
                
//this line creates the warning
$nome_cognome_parts =  @divide_name_surname( ($arr_csv[$c][0] !== null) ? $arr_csv[$c][0] : "" );
$nome = $nome_cognome_parts[0];
$cognome = $nome_cognome_parts[1];
        
// build final array  
$array_finale[$c][0] = ""; 
$array_finale[$c][1] = "";
$array_finale[$c][2] = @$arr_csv[$c][2]; //this line creates the warning
$array_finale[$c][3] = @$arr_csv[$c][3]; //this line creates the warning
$array_finale[$c][4] = @$arr_csv[$c][0]; //this line creates the warning
$array_finale[$c][5] = "";
$array_finale[$c][6] = @$arr_csv[$c][1]; //this line creates the warning
$array_finale[$c][7] = "";
$array_finale[$c][8] = $nome;
$array_finale[$c][9] = $cognome;
$array_finale[$c][10] = $progressivo;
$array_finale[$c][11] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$progressivo++;
}
```

How can I solve the problem without having to hide the warning?

Comment: Evidently $arr_csv (or possibly $arr_csv[$c]) contains a boolean (probably `false` I'd guess) but your code accesses it like it's an array. Check what `csvToArray` is doing and what it produces.

Comment: hi ADyson - this is the function to build $arr_csv:

function csvToArray($csvFile,$separatore){
 
    $file_to_read = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
 
    while (!feof($file_to_read) ) {  
        $lines[] = fgetcsv($file_to_read, 1000, $separatore);  
    }
 
    fclose($file_to_read);
    return $lines;
}
I don't understand where a boolean element can be hidden. do you have a further suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Comments are only used for brief clarification. Your question has an [edit] button under it, which you can use to improve the main post, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.

Comment: `I don't understand where a boolean element can be hidden`...well [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) can return `false`, as that documentation tells you. [Debug your code](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) to see which line (or lines) of data might be failing. Also that documentation contains usage examples show a more reliable way to loop through the file so that you don't accidentally - for example - end up trying to read a blank or non-CSV line at the end of the file. Always read the docs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: I solved the problem: as ADyson rightly said, the $arr_csv array contained the last empty element and the functions applied did not do their job well.
I processed the array with a function that eliminates empty and duplicate nested arrays and the warning disappeared.
thank you

Comment: Thank you very much ADyson.
I didn't hide the boolean, I hid the display of the warning by placing @ before the variable. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code may be trying to read non-existent lines at the end of the file.

Follow the example in the official documentation to correctly read all the rows:

```
function csvToArray($csvFile,$separatore){
    
    $file_to_read = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file_to_read, 1000, $separatore)) !== FALSE) {
        $lines[] = $data;       
    }
    
    fclose($file_to_read);
    return $lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_word_count($stringa, 1)` - this returns an array, and
`str_word_count($stringa, 1) === 2` always returns `bool(false)`. To count number of an array elements use `array_count_values()`.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't cause the error the OP is specifically asking about

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem by submitting $arr_csv to the function:

```
function eliminaArrayNested(array $array, int $indice1, int $indice2) {
  // Se l'indice non è valido, ritorna l'array originale
  if ($indice1 < 0 || $indice1 >= count($array) || $indice2 < 0 || $indice2 >= count($array)) {
    return $array;
  }

  // Crea un nuovo array senza gli array nested da eliminare
  $arrayNuovo = array();
  for ($n = 0; $n < count($array); $n++) {
    if ($n != $indice1 && $n != $indice2) {
      $arrayNuovo[] = $array[$n];
    }
  }

  // Restituisce il nuovo array
  return $arrayNuovo;
}
```

and

```
function remove_last_element_multidim_arr($array) {
    $array_length = count($array);

    if ($array_length > 0) {
        array_pop($array);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

new code:

```
$arr_csv = csvToArray($nome_file_csv,',');
$arr_csv = eliminaArrayNested(remove_last_element_multidim_arr($arr_csv),0,1);  

for($c=0; $c< count($arr_csv ); $c++){
    nome_cognome_parts = separa_nome_cognome( 
          ($arr_csv[$c][0] !== null) ? $arr_csv[$c][0] : "" );
    $nome = $nome_cognome_parts[0];
    $cognome = $nome_cognome_parts[1];      
        
    $array_finale[$c][0] = "";
    $array_finale[$c][1] = "";
    $array_finale[$c][2] = $arr_csv[$c][2];
    $array_finale[$c][3] = $arr_csv[$c][3];
    $array_finale[$c][4] = $arr_csv[$c][0];
    $array_finale[$c][5] = "";
    $array_finale[$c][6] = $arr_csv[$c][1];
    $array_finale[$c][7] = "";
    $array_finale[$c][8] = $nome;
    $array_finale[$c][9] = $cognome;
    $array_finale[$c][10] = $progressivo; 
    $array_finale[$c][11] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");            
    $progressivo++;
}
```