# How to correctly use feof() for Kattis problems in PHP

Tags: php, eof, feof

I'm currently working on Problems on the Kattis programming challenges site. I'm solving my problems with php, as that is the language I am most comfortable with. Here a link to one of the problems: https://open.kattis.com/problems/different

When I run my code locally, even via the shell as recommended by [Kattis](https://support.kattis.com/support/solutions/articles/79000120853-how-do-i-read-input-if-the-end-is-not-defined-what-is-end-of-file-) it works flawlessly. It terminates properly and everything. But when I submit my code to Kattis it always gives me a Run-Time Error. At this point I'm pretty sure that it's got to do with the End of File handling, as the way you are supposed to recognize when to output your answer is via the eof pointer. As said this works in my local shell, but as I have run into this problem in two Kattis problems that use eof for termination and both don't work I'm pretty certain something is not quite right with my eof handling on Kattis.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$Results = [];
while(feof(STDIN) === False)
  {
    $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    $data = explode(" ", $input);
    $data[0] = intval($data[0]);
    $data[1] = intval($data[1]);
    if(($data[0] - $data[1]) >= 0)
    {
      array_push($Results, ($data[0] - $data[1]));
    }
    else
    {
      array_push($Results, ($data[1] - $data[0]));
    }
  }
for($i = 0; $i < count($Results); $i++)
{
  fprintf(STDOUT, "%s", $Results[$i].PHP_EOL);
}
?>
```

I have also tried the more standard

```
while(!feof(STDIN)){}
```

But that also doesn't work.

[image]
This is the output of my code when run locally. It terminates by itself and correctly solves the sample test case Kattis provides. Also before someone suggests it, no it's not got to do with the mismatched file name, I manually paste the code into Kattis and this has worked great for the first 10+ problems that did not terminate via eof.

I have also contacted Kattis support, but that hasn't been to helpful as of yet. My question is: what is the right way to detect eof such that it works on Kattis?

Here are all the Kattis support links I have already looked at:

- [https://open.kattis.com/info/judgements#:~:text=Run%20Time%20Error%20means%20your,or%20with%20an%20uncaught%20exception](https://open.kattis.com/info/judgements#:%7E:text=Run%20Time%20Error%20means%20your,or%20with%20an%20uncaught%20exception).
- https://open.kattis.com/languages/php

Comment: Using `fscanf` worked for me: `while(fscanf(STDIN, "%s %s", $a, $b) echo abs($a - $b) . "\n";`. I'm not entirely sure why your submission isn't working, but I don't see the point in complicating it beyond this, unless there's a good performance reason to use `fgets` on harder challenges.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's one last iteration that seems to break things. The following code is accepted: `while (!feof(STDIN)) { $buf = fgets(STDIN); if ($buf) { [$a, $b] = explode(" ", $buf); echo abs($a - $b) . "\n"; }}`. To reproduce the run time error, remove the `if ($buf) {}` condition around the line processing logic.

Comment: But yeah, after seeing the linked dupe, the [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425936/6243352) of testing the return value of `fgets` directly seems better than the `!feof` idiom.

Comment: @ggorlen fgets() is significantly faster than fscanf and for more input heavy problems this singular change has made the difference between over 1 second and 0.03 seconds. http://arkanis.de/weblog/2013-09-27-fast-line-iteration-in-php here is an article examining the different reading methods.

Comment: It's good to know that there are different options, but the link you provided doesn't seem to agree with your assertion: "For simple data `fscanf()` can be quite fast", which makes sense because it saves having to do another `explode()` (and in some cases, casting) and keeps more of the work in C. Can you provide the benchmark/code for the 1 second and 0.03 seconds scenario if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: BTW, I probably should have used `%d` in the above code instead of `%s`.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we do not edit a question's title with `SOLVED` to mark the question as resolved.  Please do no do this or add resolving insights to the question body.