# fread / ob_flush / flush failing on only one file

Tags: php, fread, flush

I have a PHP application running on the web that manually downloads large binary files that are not located in the web space filesystem.

```
    while(!feof($l_file_handle)) {
        print(fread($l_file_handle, 1024*8));
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```

This always works fine except there is one file that always causes it stop and fail at around 64 MB into the file.  I have tried different values for the fread length argument (e.g. using 8 instead of 1024*8) but to no avail.  It seems like it gets tripped up whenever it encounters a certain segment of bytes in the file, and then fails in flush().

Has anyone else encountered something like this and could suggest something to try?  Thanks!

If I use a length of 1024*8, I get error messages of
AH01369: missing argument name for value to tag \xbd\x17\xc7

If I use a length of 8, it fails without those messages.

I also tried calling flush() before ob_flush(), but that didn't help.

Comment: Why don't you use `readfile()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why `while(!feof($file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425804/php-while-loop-feof-isnt-outputting-showing-everything)

Comment: Did you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  We don’t use readfile() because we are accommodating situations where we are only reading a subset of bytes from a file, which can be any GB in size.  Nevertheless, this particular problem file is being downloaded in its entirety so I will see if readfile() makes a difference.  We are opening the file as binar.  And thank you for the link about the using the feof() check… it’s possible that this is relevant to my problem, though it acts as if it’s nowhere near the end of the file when the problem occurs.