# Read an array from string

Tags: php, arrays

I think if I try to research this info more time then I'll find an answer, but I just don't have any energy anymore.
Maybe it's silly question, but I hope that you'll try to understand and help without any ridicules.  (I've been studying more than 16+ hours some other topics and always missing this one).

Question: 
I've a file which contains: 
Email name surname patronymic "\n" 
Email name surname patronymic "\n" 
etc

and I just stock on the reading this info on the array...
I need an assyc array:

```
$array = ["email" => $myEmail, "wholeName" => $name+$surname+$patronymic];
```

Maybe it could be done something in this way:

```
  foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $pair) {
            list($key, $value) = explode(' ', $pair);
            $final[] = ['email'=>$key, 'value'=>$value];
    }
```

But this code will generate only this array:

```
$final[] = ['email'=>$email, 'value'=>$name];
```

But I need surname and patronymic as well too.
Maybe someone from you know the good way for this?
It would help me a lot.

One more time: I think I'll find an answer, but I'm really tired and go to sleep and just want to wake up and find an answer here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're already good to go with your existing functionality. Make a try to `list` the remaining variables called **surname** and **patroymic** like this https://eval.in/881233

```
$str = 'Email name surname patronymic
Email name surname patronymic';

foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $pair) {
            list($key, $value, $surname, $patroymic) = explode(' ', $pair);
            $final[] = ['email'=>$key, 'value'=>$value,'surname'=>$surname, 'patroymic'=>$patroymic];
    }
print '<pre>';
print_r($final);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: if you read the file with `file()` you an skip the first explode as `file()` creates an array of lines

Comment: @rtfm Yes, `file()` will help him to read each line to a new array element. @Andrii Hordynskyi  see here for file content reading on each single array element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element

Comment: thank, guys. 
Forgot about this possibility..
Have a nice day you all :)