# Get Values Line By Line in File_GET_CONTENT

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

Let Suuppoe i am getting Text from another site is as follow

```
EXCHANGE DATA
INSTA_OPEN_MINUTE=595
INSTA_CLOSE_MINUTE=930
INSTA=86400
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=330
a1517911200,34195.94,34521.01,33482.81,33753.78,0
1,34082.71,34666.33,34008.42,34563.3,0
2,34413.16,34634.35,34108.76,34208.11,0
3,34005.76,34070.73,33849.65,34002.45,0
6,34300.47,34351.34,34115.12,34203.34,0
8,34155.95,34473.43,34028.68,34436.98,0
```

I am getting text by

```
$googleFile = file_get_contents("https://www.somewebsite.com/data/getdata?q=PRODUCTDATA");
```

So now i Want to Store Each line in New php Variable So How can i achive this. i find it on google but not valid resource found so how can i seperate all data?

Comment: Try [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: That Not works. Returns Invalid argument

Comment: `explode("\n", $googleFile)`

Comment: Strange, it works for me; will post an example as an answer.

Comment: Ok no need to an answer, read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159683/read-each-line-of-txt-file-to-new-array-element